# splitting spark column into new columns based on fields in array<string>

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark 1.6 dataframe which is of type `array<string>`. The column has key, value pairs. I would like to flatten the column and use the keys to make new columns with their values.

Here is what some the rows in my dataframe look like:

```
[{"sequence":192,"id":8697413670252052,"type":["AimLowEvent","DiscreteEvent"],"time":527638582195}]
[{"sequence":194,"id":8702167944035041,"sessionId":8697340571921940,"type":["SessionCanceled","SessionEnded"],"time":527780267698,"duration":143863999}, {"sequence":1,"id":8697340571921940,"source":"iOS","schema":{"name":"netflixApp","version":"1.8.0"},"type":["Log","Session"],"time":527636403699}, 1]
```

I can use `concat_ws` to flatten the array, but how would I make use new columns based on the data ?

EDIT:
removed

Comment: can you copy paste the dataframe after you do show in your dataframe? `{` should not be possible unless its a string.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan have done, its not pretty tho :)